# display value by decreasing order with php

Tags: php

I'm quite new to this.
I'm trying to display the content of an sql table by starting with the biggest ID.
Here's the script.

```
<?php
include("config.php");
// Get contents of the designated table
$reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM dossier');
// Display each entry one by one
while ($data = $reponse->fetch()) {
?>
<tr class="odd gradeX">
<form action='delete_dossier.php' method='post'>
    <td style="width:5%;"><?php echo $data['id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data['nom']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data['officier']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data['date']; ?></td>
    <td style="width:50%;"><?php echo $data['incident']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data['charge']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data['peine']; ?></td>
</form>
</tr>
<?php
}
$reponse->closeCursor(); // Complete query
?>
```

The answey might be evident to you but my skills with sql and php are verry rusty.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL has the innate ability to sort results via the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT <field> FROM <table> ORDER BY <field> <direction>
```

Where `<direction>` is `ASC` for ascending or `DESC` for descending. If omitted, `ASC` is assumed.

So:

```
$reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM dossier ORDER BY id DESC');
```